# PHP Get method, escaping the "&" value

Tags: php, anchor

i have this Download link that will be using a GET method, here's my code:

```
echo "<a href='dlexcel.php?pname=".s1."&year=".s2."'>DOWNLOAD</a>";
```

that will be recieve by dlexcel.php

```
$_GET['pname'].$_GET['year'];
```

the problem is, `s1` is string that can contain the a value `&`. and the string itself is not complete when $_GET is called.

i already used str_replace and preg_replace but i dont know how to. i need to pull the & out and replace it with something else, i just dont know how or what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
urlencode($s1)
```

when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL

Answer (score 1):

Try `http_build_query()`. http://www.php.net/http_build_query

```
echo '<a href="dlexcel.php?', http_build_query(array(
  'pname' => $s1,
  'year' => $s2
), '">DOWNLOAD</a>');
```

This takes care of encoding data, while building the entire query string from an array for you, meaning you aren't manually hacking it together.  Remember, there is [more than just `&` that you must encode](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).